# PTHREADS SYMFONY pass classes and constant in run() function of the class extending \Thread

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads, symfony

I've been doing quite some reading about using **pthreads with symfony**.

My problem is kind of similar to what is exposed in that question: [Multi-threading in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791153/multi-threading-in-symfony2).

In short: my back-end reaches a timeout before processing all data it should process and then it cannot send back an answer to my front-end.

Hence, trying to use different threads seems to be (one of) the solution(s) to by-pass that problem (until a certain limit, I am aware of that).

Thru the reading, I've figured out the basics about how pthreads worked, and found this article quite relevant about it: https://blog.madewithlove.be/post/thread-carefully/

I did a sample case with a basic symfony project to understand it:

The main controller class under [my_symf_project]\src\AppBundle\Controller:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        $tt = new TestThread('BOOOMSTICK');
        $tt->start();

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

The class extending Thread under: [my_symf_project]\src\AppBundle\DependencyInjection:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

    class TestThread extends \Thread {
        public function __construct($text){
            $this->text = $text;
        }

        public function run(){
            $vendorAutoload= __DIR__.'/../../../vendor/autoload.php';
            require_once  $vendorAutoload;
            require_once  __DIR__.'/ClassOutsideThread.php';

            $cot = new ClassOutsideThread(' RUN ' . ' ' . $this->text);
            $cot->show();
        }

    }
    ?>
```

And another class (outside the class extending the Thread) as well under [my_symf_project]\src\AppBundle\DependencyInjection:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

class ClassOutsideThread {
    public function __construct($text){
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    public function show(){
        echo $this->text;
    }
}
?>
```

Thru the code above I manage to display 'RUN BOOOMSTICK' on the top of the standard symfony empty project page. And I understood that is possible because I added the statement "require_once  __DIR__.'/ClassOutsideThread.php';" at the beginning of the run() function.

Now I am stuck with several questions about how **to pass to childthreads: Classes and other symfony context parameters**, thru the run() function. Here is a wishlist of what I am trying to get:

1. Classes files under the folder [my_symf_proj]\src\AppBundle: Is there a quick way to load all the classes beneath  that bundle, like the autoload concerning the 'vendor' folder that is used in my class TestThread (taken from: [Boostraping symfony 2 for pthread from command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315393/boostraping-symfony-2-for-pthread-from-command))?
2. I'd like to use symfony logger in the run() function. I've tried: $GLOBALS['kernel']->getContainer()->get('logger'), but I get a big void in the [my_symf_proj]  \var\logs\dev.log, so I wonder how to access $GLOBALS['kernel']->getContainer() thru a childthread?
3. I want to use my Doctrine connection to the DB (the one corresponding to the symfony parameters set) in the run() function. How can I do that? (As well I've tried $GLOBALS['kernel']->getContainer()->get('dbal.connection'), but it does not seem to work out.)

PS: I am aware that using $GLOBALS['kernel']->getContainer() is not a symfony best practice also in that particular childthreads situation, it seems a convenient option to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thru the hints that have been provided, I manage to get it to work. Here an example of a thread in symfony 3.0.*

Replace the class TestThread which is in the question by the following one and you'll see that the symfony context gets to the childthread:

```
        class TestThread extends \Thread {
        public function __construct($text){


                $this->text = $text;
            $this->kernelName = $GLOBALS['kernel']->getName();
            $this->kernelEnv = $GLOBALS['kernel']->getEnvironment();
            $this->kernelDebug = $GLOBALS['kernel']->isDebug();

        }

        public function run(){
           require_once __DIR__.'/../../../app/autoload.php';
           require_once __DIR__.'/../../../app/AppKernel.php';



            $kernelInThread = new \AppKernel($this->kernelEnv, $this->kernelDebug);
            $kernelInThread->loadClassCache();
            $kernelInThread->boot();


            $container = $kernelInThread->getContainer();


            $log = $container->get('logger');

            $log->info('THIS IS WORKING NOW');

            $con = $container->get('doctrine.dbal.default_connection');
            $q = new PdoQuery($con);
                $c = $q->getConnection()->prepare('select field from table');

             $c->execute();
             $res = $c->fetchAll();
             var_dump($res); 



            echo 'the end </br>';
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952438/symfony-doctrine-entity-manager-injected-in-thread)

1 You can use something like

```
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../../../../../../vendor/autoload.php';
```

2-3 If you don't have to share objects between thread you can easily do inside your run method:

```
$kernel = new \AppKernel($this->env, $this->debug);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel->boot();
$this->container = $kernel->getContainer();
$this->container->get('doctrine_mongodb');
.....
```

Comment: as soon as I put  "require_once  '/../../../var/bootstrap.php.cache';" before "require_one '/../../../app/autoload.php';" the run() function doesn't work at all (no echo message displayed). I run on Symfony 3.0.2 for this test, may I ask which version do you use? In any case thank you for providing me new feedback about it, I'll look more into your solution, if you did it, it is certainly possible to achieve it on my side, also I've switched my researches to rabbitMQ as a solution to process async work (but I am considering to use both: thread and MQ to optimize async work).

Comment: We are using symfony 2.7.10(last stable). I don't know if v3 is different.

Comment: Getting back to you, I went back to symfony 2.7.10, looked again at the link you suggested and finally nailed it. Then when I am back on symfony 3.0.*, it definetely seems to have a problem to load '__DIR__.'/../../../var/bootstrap.php.cache' on v3.0.*  but it can work without that. I won't investigate php threads further on right now because I implemented rabbitMQ, it does the async work fine, and I have to progress on other topics. But I keep this example for a near future, and will post my solution.